# Solution to broken MEDIA 1.X module Image embed + CKEditor. the final submit button doesn't work

Tags: media, wysiwyg

Latest stable Drupal 7, Media 1.x, and CKEditor module (with latest CKeditor library).

When you go to upload an image, and embed it inside of the body area, the final submit after you've uploaded your image, or chosen an image from the library, button doesn't work.

It just generates a nasty javascript error.

see the screen shot here : http://alphex.com/z/js_errors-20130507-124341.jpg

Anyone seen this, have a solution?

Thanks.